How to have efficient separation of data and operation in javascript/typescript?
I learnt typescript in a hurry and still a newbie. Coming from a functional background  I am used to seperate object data from its methods. For example let us consider a simple data object that  i will want to augment as my code base grow :
export interface Data {
  readonly value: number;
}

export function Data(value: number): Data {
  return { value };
}

const data: Data = Data(2);
console.info(data); //output { value : 2 }

Data is a central brick of my code since it contains all the data defining a core object of my business model.  My application growing in feature I want to augment it with dedicated methods.
I thought of two approaches.
I can use the "companion object" pattern :
export namespace Data {
  export function incr(self: Data): Data {
    return Data(self.value + 1);
  }
}

console.info(data); //output { value : 2 }
Data.incr(data);

With this approach data stay a simple data object, and I can enrich it. However, each time I will use it I will have a bloated syntax
I can use the interface pattern  :
export namespace Data {
  export function Ops(self: Data) {
    return {
      self : self,
      incr(): Data(self.value + 1);
     }
  }
}

const data_withops = Data.Ops({ value : 2 });
console.info(data_withops.self); //output { value : 2 }
data_withops.incr() 

It is less bloated but I still have to manually encapsulate/decapsulate the data.
I can inject the operators into the data
export interface Data {
  readonly value: number,
  incr(): Data
}


const data: Data = Data(2);
console.info(data); //output { value : 2, incr : Function }

But then the object is bloated, bloating my console, my cache and my network.
Is it possible to do it without any of those problems?

data is not bloated : console.info(data); //output { value : 2 }
user of the object does not have to care about "loading/unloading" the operators
user has a light syntax : "data.incr()" is defined

I thought it would works with the prototypes but I didn't succeed
declare global {
  export interface Data {
    incr(this: Data): number;
  }
}

Data.prototype.incr = function (this: Data): Data {
  return Data(this.value + 1);
};

console.info(data); //output { value : 2 }
data.incr();


• I don't understand where anything is "bloated" here. All of this code is fairly small. Please [edit] to make it very clear exactly what is "bloated"  • Why are you doing this without classes? This would be trivial with a class, as shown in this playground link. If you need to do merging and augmenting, you can still do it with a class, as shown here.  What, specifically, is the problem with such an approach?

Regarding ... "I thought it would works with the prototypes but I didn't succeed" ... It will work as soon as the OP actually implements Data as constructor function (an interface is nothing real) and in addition does create data as an instance of Data like ... const data = new Data(2);. What this solution does not achieve is a data instance with a read-only (as the OP's Data interface does demand) value since the implementation of Data.prototype.incr relies on a public value property.

thank you for your answers. that was what I was searching for

fyi, by bloated I mean than my object are parsed as { value : 2, incr : [Function incr]  }, all the functions being repeated in big recursive structure. So it bloats my memory. And manually separating data would bloat my code.  with the class approach I do have {"value":2} while  i can do data.incr(). So that was the answer.  I feel a little dump since it was so unatural of me but I didn't have time to learn academically js and I was advised against class.

@CooLHibou You really should use a class here. Make it immutable. Continue writing your methods like you did, returning new instances. There is nothing wrong with functional object-orientated programming, see Scala.

@CooLHibou ... Regarding all the answers / comments, are there any questions left?

@Peter Seliger  No. I learnt than interface/class is the way to go in typescript as it allows a concise, ergonomic and economic codebase which will be really polyvalent thanks to prototypes.  three complementary functionalities are usefull in this style : pulbic readonly constructors, module augmentation and fine type tuning with "this" in function arguments.  Right now I Um completely rewriting my codebase with all of this and the benefits are humongous. Thanks everyone!

@CooLHibou ... What are "public readonly constructors"?

@Peter Seliger see parameter properties.  Also experimented with mixins to achieve a true separation of data (class with only public read only constructors) and methods ( developped as "modules" that extends the data class in separate files and added with the "alternative pattern" of the link about mixins) This coding style is suited for dsl/free monad pattern  largely explored in languages like scala.

@CooLHibou ... 1/2 ... Nothing there points to at what you've described as "public readonly constructors" (because there is not such a thing, neither in JS nor in TS). If I got it correctly, what you want to achieve is creating instances of a Data type, where you want the Data class to be implemented in a way that you describe as ... (and I try to paraphrase it) ... "Enabling (enumerable?) read-only properties at such a data type along with (non enumerable / not directly owned) methods which still can mutate those properties' values." (and that's just the OO design part.) ...

@CooLHibou ... 2/2 ... "The additional goal is to achieve as well the separation of the pure data-value related implementation from the part which does access/mutate these data values." (that's the part which covers the file structure of the code base.) In case all assumption are correct, the author might think about switching from TS to pure JS since with the former it is much harder to achieve and reliably keep true privacy while in the same time having to achieve any other goal with an implementation that spreads over more than just one module. And regarding mixins, TS did screw them.

@Peter Seliger, I should have given a deeper context. What  i am trying to achieve is what  i would call a "algebra-oriented" programming style that has been popularized notably by scala 3 and its typelevel community. When I say "public readonly constructors" please read "constructors that only have public readonly parameters". Such classes are pure data classes, similarly to scala's case classes. If  i have in one hand a space of such data classes, and in another, functions on objects within this space, I can achieve a truly functional style.

@Peter Seliger, Thanks to this thread recommandation about using classes, one can decide for each of those functions, that there is one "leading" parameter (for a human point of view). Using this leading parameter as the reference to call the function is a matter of syntaxic sugar (see the examples of my initial posts). However, as the references to the function are not hardly linked to the object in memory, the data object remains light contrary to my examples that suceeded to comply with this syntaxic sugar. That's why for me it's the good practice in TS

@Peter Seliger, What I call an algebra is for example a List which is a disjonctive data object that defines a space of either Nil or  Cons(a,List). When you adopt such a style you want to lay down a set of "words" (data) that capture the aspects of your business model as well as a set of "verbs" (functions) to compose them. This results in a codebase efficient, versatile and extensible. It woul be hard to synthetise what tooks me year to learn but if you are interested, I can orient toward this two videos as well as the works of their respective authors.

1 2

@Peter Seliger, Concerning JS over TS from my background  I can not understand why someone would want without a strong type checker ! =)  but yes I am currently having a hard time with TS mixins, which seems to be a little stronger that what I need, so I am trying to solve those circular dependencies in the most simple way. Thank you for your concern.

@CooLHibou ... 1/4 ... JS is so flexible and expressive, that creating/implementing domain specific solutions/languages is an easy and enjoyable thing. One even could aim for a full functional (I consider Promise to be a monad) based DSL. Thus, I really would like to see what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you open another thread, link to it from this comment section, and provide more detailed insights into your favored design.

@CooLHibou ... 2/4 ... It would be even more helpful if you do provide real example code of an actual implementation which does solve the problem in the language you feel is best suited for such a task.

@CooLHibou ... 3/4 ... And regarding yours ... "Concerning JS over TS from my background I can not understand why someone would want without a strong type checker ! =)" ...  because you firstly have to know in an out the actual language's (JS) core features; because if you do not know the language TS transpiles into (JS), you fall for its special virtual constructs and its false promises like private annotations which actually create vulnerable full public type/object systems; ...

@CooLHibou ... 4/4 ... because interfaces and types are not a guarantee that at runtime the system can not be screwed ... worse it most likely will, because almost no-one, except the ones with a strong JS background, will implement additional type checks, intended type casts or even the raising of meaningful type/reference errors where it is appropriate due to the false believe that TS is a strongly typed language. The only truth are carefully written tests. A successful compilation alone is not reliable at all. If one wants type checks at development level, jsDoc is as good as is a ts-config.

@Peter Seliger. Promise is de facto a monad, which is the good base for an IO monad (see scala's cats-effect library). However, there are limitations. Typescript not naturally integrates higher kinded type nor Javascript strong concurrency feature like greenthread. For those reason I consider scala 3 as, by design, the best language for the task. Notably enhanced by cats and cats effect, or zio libraries.  Étudier cette libraire est aussi tres instructif.

@Peter Seliger, concerning Ts  i agree with everything you said. Having learnt TS without JS has already created confusion that my js expert friend has clarified by remaining me of the tranpiling process. TS is clearly not a strong typed language, since it does not know nothing about the instances, and is not so rigorus. And tests is therefor the best way to keep your mind in peace.

@Peter Seliger.Concerning my code,  unfortunately I do not want to show it right now, because it is for an incubating startup. However it will eventually be open sourced and I will contact you if you are interested. If you want to discuss of it in private, you can contact me.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This feels like it's begging to be a class.
class Data {
    value:number;

    constructor(value:number){
        this.value = value
    }

    increment(incrementAmount:number){
        this.value = this.value + incrementAmount
    }
}


If by "separate" an object from its methods all you mean is that the methods shouldn't be added individually to each instance, then by far the most common way to do things like this is with a class, which automatically happens via prototypical inheritance:
class Data {
    readonly value: number;
    constructor(value: number) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    incr(): Data {
        return new Data(this.value + 1);
    }
}

const data: Data = new Data(2);
console.log(data); // {value: 2}
const nextData = data.incr();
console.log(nextData) // {value: 3}

If you really need to "separate" it even further and put the methods in some separate file, you can just add these methods to the class prototype and use declaration merging to let TypeScript know about it:
// original class
class Data {
    readonly value: number;
    constructor(value: number) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
        
// merge in a method in some other place
interface Data {
    incr(): Data;
}
Data.prototype.incr = function (this: Data) {
    return new Data(this.value + 1)
}
    
const data: Data = new Data(2);
console.log(data); // { value: 2 }
const nextData = data.incr();
console.log(nextData) // {value: 3}

In both of these cases you are mutating the state of your class instances (e.g., this.value = value). If you really need immutable(ish) functional data structures then you can still use prototypical inheritance, but you'll find yourself jumping through hoops like manually calling Object.create():
// original class-like functions
interface Data {
    readonly value: number
}
function Data(value: number): Data {
    return Object.create(Data.prototype, {
        value: { value: value, enumerable: true }
    })
}


// merge in a method in some other place
interface Data {
    incr(): Data;
}
Data.prototype.incr = function (this: Data) {
    return Data(this.value + 1)
}

const data: Data = Data(2);
console.log(data); // {value: 2}
const nextData = data.incr();
console.log(nextData) // {value: 3}

This doesn't seem like an obvious improvement.  The usual approach is to just use class declarations until and unless you have some strong reason not to.
Playground link to code

"you are mutating the state of your class instances (e.g., this.value = value)." - I'd argue that all this does is initialise the state, which is fine in the constructor. And TypeScript readonly agrees. The incr method doesn't mutate anything.

I don't understand how it works on separate files! How do you import the original Data (with the data) in the new file (with the operator) without creating name coflict? How do you import the different implementation into another file that will use it? Can you have different «aspects» (set of operations) on different files but a user of this object is able to import everything with one import  ? (hence, the user is blind about the microlithic arrchitecture)?

You'd use export and import and module augmentation. That's a pretty large subject and not directly in scope for the question. You might want to read the TypeScript handbook, especially the sections on modules and declaration merging, and then open a new question post if you still can't figure it out.

module augmentation <3

From my above comment ...

Regarding ... "I thought it would works with the prototypes but I didn't succeed" ... It will work as soon as the OP actually implements Data as constructor function (an interface is nothing real) and in addition does create data as an instance of Data like ... const data = new Data(2);. What this solution does not achieve is a data instance with a read-only (as the OP's Data interface does demand) value since the implementation of Data.prototype.incr relies on a public value property.

But class and features like private properties together with defined property getters are capable of protected data values which in public are read-only but also can be mutated exclusively by (even prototypal) methods which are declared within the class' body.
The implementation of the next provided example code does fulfill any of the OP's requirements ...

readonly value: number;

data is not bloated ... console.info(data); // output { value : 2 },

user of the object does not have to care about "loading/unloading" the operators,

user has a light syntax ... data.incrementValue() is defined.




// provide a non number value.
const data = createData('4');

console.log('data ...', data);
console.log('\n');

console.log('data.incrementValue ...', data.incrementValue);
console.log('data.valueOf ...', data.valueOf);
console.log('data.toString ...', data.toString);

console.log('\n');
console.log(
  'data.value = data.value + 100 ...',
  (data.value = data.value + 100)
);
console.log('data.value ...', data.value);

console.log('\n');
console.log(
  'data.incrementValue().incrementValue() ...',
  data.incrementValue().incrementValue()
);
console.log('data.value ...', data.value);
console.log('\n');

console.log('data.valueOf() ...', data.valueOf());
console.log('data.toString() ...', data.toString());
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>
// local scope of the `Data` module.


// - helper function which keeps the constructor's body slender.

function initializeOwnProperties(instance, privateState, ...args) {
  const [value/*, anotherValue */] = args;

  Object
    .assign(privateState, {
      value: Number(value)/*,
      anotherValue: castAndOrSanitize(anotherValue)*/,
    });

  // enumerable and read-only due to getter only implementation/s.

  Reflect
    .defineProperty(instance, 'value', {
      enumerable: true,
      get: () => privateState.value,
    });/*

  Reflect
    .defineProperty(instance, 'anotherValue', {
      enumerable: true,
      get: () => privateState.anotherValue,
    })*/
}


class Data {

  // private (and secretly shared) state.
  #state = {};

  constructor(...args) {
    // forward all values to an initialzing helper.
    initializeOwnProperties(this, this.#state, ...args);
  }

  // (non enumerable) prototypal methods working upon private state.

  incrementValue() {
    ++this.#state.value;
    
    return this;
  }

  valueOf() {
    // the pure data at any given time as deep structured clone.
    return structuredClone(this.#state);
  }
  toJSON() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.#state);
  }
  toString() {
    return this.toJSON();
  }
}

// - a single factory function as the module's only export
//   in order to not having to expose the `Data` class itself.

/* export */function createData(...args) {
  return new Data(...args)
}
</script>



A class-less but "constructor-function and constructor.prototype only" implementation in its modern variant that equals the class based implementation of the above example's code, and thus, covering every single of the OP's requirements as well, might look similar to the next provided code ...


// provide a non number value.
const data = createData('4');

console.log('data ...', data);
console.log('\n');

console.log('data.incrementValue ...', data.incrementValue);
console.log('data.valueOf ...', data.valueOf);
console.log('data.toString ...', data.toString);

console.log('\n');
console.log(
  'data.value = data.value + 100 ...',
  (data.value = data.value + 100)
);
console.log('data.value ...', data.value);

console.log('\n');
console.log(
  'data.incrementValue().incrementValue() ...',
  data.incrementValue().incrementValue()
);
console.log('data.value ...', data.value);
console.log('\n');

console.log('data.valueOf() ...', data.valueOf());
console.log('data.toString() ...', data.toString());
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>
// local scope of the `Data` module.

const stateRegistry = new WeakMap;


// - prototypal methods working upon private state
//   saved into the `WeakMap` based `stateRegistry`.

function incrementValue() {
  const state = stateRegistry.get(this);

  ++state.value;

  stateRegistry.set(this, state);

  return this;
}

function valueOf() {
  // the pure data at any given time as deep structured clone.
  return structuredClone(stateRegistry.get(this));
}
function toJSON() {
  return JSON.stringify(stateRegistry.get(this));
}
function toString() {
  return this.toJSON();
}


// - helper function which keeps the constructor's body slender.
//
// NOTE:
// - it's exactly the same implementation as the class based one.

function initializeOwnProperties(instance, privateState, ...args) {
  const [value/*, anotherValue */] = args;

  Object
    .assign(privateState, {
      value: Number(value)/*,
      anotherValue: castAndOrSanitize(anotherValue)*/,
    });

  // enumerable and read-only due to getter only implementation/s.

  Reflect
    .defineProperty(instance, 'value', {
      enumerable: true,
      get: () => privateState.value,
    });/*

  Reflect
    .defineProperty(instance, 'anotherValue', {
      enumerable: true,
      get: () => privateState.anotherValue,
    })*/
}


// - the `Data` constructor function.

function Data(...args) {

  // instantiation guard.
  if (!(this instanceof Data)) {
    throw new TypeError(
      "Failed to construct 'Data'. Please use the 'new' operator."
    );
  }

  // locally scoped private (and secretly shared) state.
  const state = {};

  // forward all values to an initialzing helper.
  initializeOwnProperties(this, state, ...args)

  // - saving the instance specific private state
  //   into the module scoped `stateRegistry`.

  stateRegistry.set(this, state);
}

// - configuring the (non enumerable) prototypal method definitions.

Object
  .defineProperties(Data.prototype, {

    incrementValue: {
      configurable: true, writable: true, value: incrementValue,
    },

    valueOf: {
      configurable: true, writable: true, value: valueOf,
    },
    toJSON: {
      configurable: true, writable: true, value: toJSON,
    },
    toString: {
      configurable: true, writable: true, value: toString,
    },
  });

// - a single factory function as the module's only export in
//   order to not having to expose the `Data` implementation.

/* export */function createData(...args) {
  return new Data(...args)
}
</script>



And the "constructor-function only" version, without the usage of a WeakMap based registry, has to drop the usage of prototype based methods too, thus, it adds additional costs/weight to every created instance due to the handling of exclusively closure based privacy.
But even this approach, though it implements the methods as own methods (not as prototypal ones), thus adding some fat to each instance, does meet any of the OP's requirements ...


// provide a non number value.
const data = createData('4');

console.log('data ...', data);
console.log('\n');

console.log('data.incrementValue ...', data.incrementValue);
console.log('data.valueOf ...', data.valueOf);
console.log('data.toString ...', data.toString);

console.log('\n');
console.log(
  'data.value = data.value + 100 ...',
  (data.value = data.value + 100)
);
console.log('data.value ...', data.value);

console.log('\n');
console.log(
  'data.incrementValue().incrementValue() ...',
  data.incrementValue().incrementValue()
);
console.log('data.value ...', data.value);
console.log('\n');

console.log('data.valueOf() ...', data.valueOf());
console.log('data.toString() ...', data.toString());
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>
// - the `Data` constructor function.

function Data(value/*, anotherValue */) {

  // instantiation guard.
  if (!(this instanceof Data)) {
    throw new TypeError(
      "Failed to construct 'Data'. Please use the 'new' operator."
    );
  }

  // locally scoped private state.
  const state = {};

  Object
    .assign(state, {
      value: Number(value)/*,
      anotherValue: castAndOrSanitize(anotherValue)*/,
    });

  Object
    .defineProperties(this, {

      // read-only due to getter only implementation/s.

      value: {
        enumerable: true,
        get: () => state.value,
      }/*,
      anotherValue: {
        enumerable: true,
        get: () => state.anotherValue,
      }*/,

      // configuring the own method definitions.

      incrementValue: {
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: () => { ++state.value; return this; },
      },

      valueOf: {
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        // the pure data at any given time as deep structured clone.
        value: () => structuredClone(state),
      },
      toJSON: {
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: () => JSON.stringify(state),
      },
      toString: {
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: () => this.toJSON(),
      },
    });
}

// - a single factory function as the module's only export in
//   order to not having to expose the `Data` implementation.

/* export */function createData(...args) {
  return new Data(...args)
}
</script>




Why do you define the value getter with Reflect.defineProperty instead of using ordinary getter syntax in the class? Also in the last example, why not just define value as part of the Object.defineProperties call?

@Bergi ... I had it like that before, writing ... get value() { return this.#state.value; } directly into the class body. But in that way value becomes a non enumerable property which is not what the OP was asking for. Only the custom defined property getter within the constructor-function's body allows value to be implemented as protected enumerable property. Amongst the OP's criteria there was ... "readonly value: number;" and "data is not bloated ... console.info(data); // output { value : 2 }".

@Bergi ... 2/2 ... Regarding ... "Also in the last example, why not just define value as part of the Object.defineProperties call?" ... You're right. That's an leftover from my refactoring. I was blind to that. I'm going to fix it.
